# PHP $_POST strange behavior, only works 2nd time form is posted

Tags: php, forms, post

I'm genuinely stuck on something VERY irritating. After a couple of hours of trying everything I know I've ended up here to see if anyone can help. Here's the general idea.

I want one certain page to be available with a password sent via a form. There is no user, and the password will not change. This should be easy, right!

I've got a form which submits with the method set to post, and the action set to `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. The plan is, when the password variable I've pre-defined matches what is typed in the form, one set of content shows on the page, when it doesn't you get a different set of content (a form).

Here's what's weird. When looking at a `print_r` I see whatever I submit in the form in the array, but when I put the right password in the array fills, then empties quickly. I see this on the page reload. It completely empties itself. Even stranger, the 2nd time I do this, it works. What am I missing here? I'd love to know!

Many thanks, and Merry Christmas.

---- some code ----

The form

```
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
            <label for="pass" id="pass">Password:</label>
        <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Yes" />
    </form>
```

Some PHP from the top of the file;

```
$pass = '12846565488374';
if($_POST['pass']){ $login = $_POST['pass']; } else { $login = 'empty'; }
if($login != $pass) { $show = 0; } elseif($login == $pass){ $show = 1; }
```

----- solved ------

Turns out this was a JS plugin reloading the page without me knowing.

Comment: Changing the action to the hardcoded page, just incase that's the issue, but I don't think it is. What else can I try? If it's wiping out what's in $_POST I really don't know what to do.

Comment: It's hard to give help when there is no active examples of your code

Comment: Well there's a bit, but really unless I'm just so tired I can't see something obvious - this is stuff I've done many times.

Comment: use `isset($_POST['pass'])`, not just `$_POST['pass']` in your condition

Comment: What if someone uses `empty` as his password? Use `$login = null` or an empty string instead!

Comment: So you are trying to check `$_POST['pass']; is equal to `$pass` ? if so, then it will display a specific page?

Comment: The comparison, yes, but it just displays different content on the same page based on the success of failure of that clause.

Comment: @thiefmaster - yeah, I know...but this is really something I'm literally throwing together for someone or it would be WAY more secure. Don't worry!

Comment: @Dan It would be best to impliment security in your development phases as it is easier than going back over your finished product and making changes

Comment: @Dan,Not sure what you mean by "I see this on the page reload. It [the $_POST array?] completely empties itself". What exactly do you see? sounds like a refresh

Comment: @matanya - while the page loads I see the data in the print_r array, and then the array just empties like it's being wiped. I can't think of any else I should say?? I have WordPress running on my server so there are redirect in the .htaccess? I read that could be a conflict, but that doesn't make sense either because a wrong password does not get wiped in the array.

Comment: It might be your JavaScript code, resubmitting or something. Hard to tell without seeing the entire code

Comment: God lord. It's the JS plugin I'm running. I've never seen anything like this. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Of course it does - he's not showing the whole code...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if(isset($_POST['pass']) AND $_POST['pass'] == $pass) {
     $show = 1;
} else {
     $show = 0;
}
```

Copied from the comment below:

PHP can't update anything after the page is loaded from the server... You can only use refresh or JS/AJAX to change the content. It would be much easier if you uploaded the whole page somewhere.

Comment: Hi, this works, but I see it flash "1" and then back to zero when I hit submit. That's the strange behavior I'm talking about.

Comment: Is there something refreshing your page if the password is correct?

Comment: Nope, not that I know of. The rest is so simple. It's an IF clause with a load of html and JS in each part. 

if($show == true){ stuff } else { the form on failure }

Comment: That's weird because PHP can't update anything after the page is loaded from the server... You can only use refresh or JS/AJAX to change the content. It would be much easier if you uploaded the whole page somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['pass']))
    {

        if ($_POST['pass'] == $pass)
        {
            $show = 1; 
            echo $show;
        }
        else
        {
            $show = 0;
            echo $show;
        }
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        <label for="pass" id="pass">Password:</label>
    <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Yes" />
</form>
```

perhaps something like this?

**the purpose for the `echo` is to show when the correct password is entered, $show changes to 1 and when wrong, changed to 0**

*Edit:*

Your Parameters Checking for `$show`

```
<?php
    if (isset($show) AND $show === 1)
    {
        echo "The Variable Is Set To 1"; 
    }
    elseif (isset($show) AND $show === 0)
    {
        echo "The Variable Is Set To 0";
    }
?>
```

This is tested and working with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    <?PHP
if(isset($_POST['pass'])
    {
    $pass = '12846565488374';
    ($_POST['pass'] == $pass)? $show = 1 : $show = 0;
    echo $show;
    }
    else
        {
?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
            <label for="pass" id="pass">Password:</label>
        <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Yes" />
    </form>
<?PHP
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help everyone - as Matanya said, it was indeed a Javascript issue that was reloading the page. It's a music player and it was placed the "true" part of the IF statement. I don't understand why it has this effect, but at least I know. I thought the error would be in my PHP. Here's the player in question: SCM Music Player http://scmplayer.net

Thanks again.

Comment: Didn't I ask you like 15 minutes ago whether there was something that was refreshing the page if the password is correct? :)

Comment: I literally never thought this was possible. What a colossal waste of two hours and everyones time. : (

Comment: Hah, no worries, what's important is that you've sorted it out! :)